# Can somebody explain the following code in English?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I understand regex broadly but I hoped somebody could help understand this a bit better. I'm using it to insert a double new line where there was only one before- it almost works, but not quite. I stole this from 'github flavored markdown' - it modifies to support new lines more intuitively.

```
 cleaned.gsub!(/^[\w\<][^\n]*\n+/) do |x|
      x =~ /\n{2}/ ? x : (x.strip!; x << "  \n")
 end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/^` - From beginning of the string:

`[\w\<]` -  Match any latter character or Open angle bracket. After that:

`[^\n]*`  - There should be any non-new line characters, and

`\n+/` - at the end should be one or many new lines.

So then on every match code replaces with:

If matched code contains two new-lines, then keep it untouched.

Otherwise strip it an add space and new line at the end.